# Follow-along videos for the most effective stretching routine

Tags: stretching, programs

I'm looking to increase range of motion, primarily for certain lifts (e.g. back and front squat), for acro yoga (e.g. hamstrings), and general flexibility (e.g. for yoga).

I've done some research into stretching and it appears that [PNF is the most effective form of stretching for increasing ROM](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17052131).

According to that study, it should be done once or twice a week. According to Brad Appleton's *Stretching and Flexibility*, [PNF should be performed every other day](https://web.mit.edu/tkd/stretch/stretching_5.html#SEC60). Only one PNF technique per muscle group stretched in a given stretching session is [sufficient](https://web.mit.edu/tkd/stretch/stretching_4.html#SEC36), and one *hold-relax* technique lasts about a minute, which suggests that a daily PNF session should not last more than 15 minutes. Somewhere else I've read that 8 minutes is the minimum effective dose, because PNF is quite strenuous.

What would be a simple, clear (a la Jeremy Ethier or Jeff Nippard), video playlist with full-body PNF stretches that could be followed along unassisted 2-3x per week, for less than 15 minutes per day?

Happy to pay for such a course, because on YouTube I've only found videos like "[full-body 60-minute PNF stretch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1aiTsZtPoRQ)" or [lower-body only](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFMysSYVp8g), or [not follow-along](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oM9pPjGudic) etc.

Comment: What’s the goal here? Outside of improving mobility challenges for specific movements, stretching has been shown to improve stretching related outcomes and not much else. Do you have any mobility challenges you are trying to overcome? If you don’t have any particular mobility concerns, what longitudinal outcomes are you trying to achieve? Or to put it another way, most effective *for what exactly*? If *general flexibility* is your primary goal, you should clearly state that in the question.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov: the first sentence of the OP mentioned "for increasing ROM", but I've added a lead paragraph clarifying my goals. Thanks for the prompt.